# Runner https://gitlab.com... is not healthy and will be disabled

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to create a runner but have an issue with it:

```
# IdeaProjects\git_ci>gitlab-runner register
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=8084 revision=8fa89735 version=13.6.0
- Enter the GitLab instance URL (for example, https://gitlab.com/):
#: https://gitlab.com/
- Enter the registration token:
#: Aoedt1XjyTSb8WahsyM
- Enter a description for the runner:
#: Runner11
- Enter tags for the runner (comma-separated):
#: tag1
Registering runner... succeeded                     runner=Adoedt1X
- Enter an executor: docker, virtualbox, docker-ssh+machine, shell, ssh, docker+machine, kubernetes, custom, docker-windows, docker-ssh, parallels:
#: shell
```

I try to run runner immediately after that and try to run after that I marks **Run untagged jobs** but anyway I have the error in the result:

[image]

I see in the error line the wrong URI, possible this is a reason, but I do not know - how and why this URI got such value:

[image]

- I spent more than 2 days and nothing help. How to correctly register/run a runner?

And the additional question - why I need several runners if one runner can execute many jobs? Why do I need to create a runner if all works fine with a "runner by default"?

Comment: If you have installed the gitlab-runner as a service, then you don't have to run the command `gitlab-runner run` after every runner registration. Please follow this guide to setup up gitlab-runner correctly in windows. https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about permissions: for Windows we need to run `cmd` with administrator permissions, and then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this:

1. Unregister the runner

   a. List all runners:  `.\gitlab-runner.exe list`

   b.Unregister the runner using the token:  `.\gitlab-runner.exe unregister --url http://git-xxx.com --token TOKEN_NAME`

   c. Unregister the runner using name: `.\gitlab-runner.exe unregister --name NAME`
2. Delete runner from `config.toml` file and start the runner.